# Set Parameter value from select query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two parameter

```
DECLARE @nOdc_Id VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @nProject_Id VARCHAR(50)
```

And a Select Query

```
Select nOdc_Id ,nProject_Id  From ProjectTable Where ProjectId='53'
```

Now I want to set the parameter's value as

```
Set @=nOdc_Id =nOdc_Id 
And @nProject_Id =nProject_Id
```

Please any one help how can I implement this in StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 16):

```
Select @nOdc_Id = nOdc_Id, 
       @nProject_Id = nProject_Id  
From ProjectTable 
Where ProjectId = 53
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do like this. There are more approaches.

```
SET @nOdc_Id = (select nOdc_Id From ProjectTable Where ProjectId='53');
SET @nProject_Id = (select nProject_Id From ProjectTable Where ProjectId='53');
```

Comment: This approach is recommended in Microsoft publications. In case that the SELECT statement inside brackets unexpectedly returns more than one row error would be raised - which is desired. If SELECT @nOdc_Id= nOdc_ID FROM ProjectTable approach would be used no error would be raised in case of more than one row returned, you would just end up with wrong data without knowing it.

Comment: @Ivan__83 so i using only this approach(or used when i worked with T-SQL).

Comment: I don't know how this situation is handled in other RDBMSs. But this approach is preferred in TSQL.

Answer (score 3):

like this:

```
DECLARE @nOdc_Id VARCHAR(50) 
DECLARE @nProject_Id VARCHAR(50) 

Select @nOdc_Id = nOdc_Id From ProjectTable Where ProjectId='53' 
select @nProject_Id  = nProject_Id From ProjectTable Where ProjectId='53'
```